# How to capture Angular component errors thrown in lifecycle methods?

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I have an Angular component with required inputs, and I throw an error if they are not provided.

```ts
export class FormValidationMessageComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() form!: NgForm;
  @Input() field!: NgModel;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (typeof this.form === 'undefined') throw new Error(`The 'form' property is not set!`);
    if (typeof this.field === 'undefined') throw new Error(`The 'field' property is not set!`);
  }
}
```

How can I test this behavior?  It does throw an error in my test when nothing is provided, but how do I capture this in my `expect`?

```ts
let component: FormValidationMessageComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<FormValidationMessageComponent>;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [FormValidationMessageComponent],
  });
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FormValidationMessageComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it('should throw an error when the `form` input is not provided', () => {
  const onInitSpy = spyOn(component, 'ngOnInit');
  component.field = {} as NgModel;

  fixture.detectChanges(); //Triggers ngOnInit()

  expect(onInitSpy).toThrow();
});
```

The above test still throws an error and the test fails

```
Error: The 'form' property is not set!
```

I have also tried `expect(component).toThrow();` with the same results